# In what case(s) does moving assets from a US broker to another US broker incur capital gains taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, transfer, securities

I read on https://www.investingsimple.com/transfer-fidelity-to-charles-schwab/:

> Before you [move assets from Fidelity to Charles Schwab], you ought to be aware of potential capital gains taxes. You will also have to pay Fidelity's ACATS transfer fee.

In what case(s) does moving assets from a US broker to another US broker incur capital gains taxes?

I'm mostly interested in in-kind security transfer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm mostly interested in in-kind security transfer.

Moving assets incur capital gains taxes if assets have to be converted into cash. This is mentioned a little bit before in the text:

> ...Or you may decide to liquidate some assets and transfer cash to Schwab. However, there may be capital gains tax implications if you make a profit from the sale.

Your broker should be able to tell you if the holdings you have can be moved in-kind or have to be liquidated. For most retail investments you should be able to do a ACATS in-kind transfer and not trigger any tax event.